# non normal distribution and normal distribution ttest

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test

I have one data is normal distribution **(VAR00004)** and another data is non normal distribution **(VAR00002)**. If I want to compare this both data, what should I do in the T-test or is there another available test?

[image]

The both Graphs are showing here too.
[image]
[image]

Comment: How you want to handle this depends on a couple of things.  1) What hypothesis you want to test.  That is, if you are interested in the means *per se*.  2) The distribution of the data (or underlying population) of the two groups.  If one is very skewed, comparing means may not be the most meaningful comparison. ... It may be helpful if you can post histograms of each group of observations.

Comment: @SalMangiafico I have updated my post. thks

Comment: My two cents:  The distributions are somewhat similar.  And the sample size is relatively small. ... If you are interested in comparing means, a permutation test should work well.  However, for comparing two samples, there are many measures you could look at.  There are the means.  The Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test will examine the probability that an observation in one group will be larger than an observation in another group (stochastic dominance).  You could also compare medians, another quantile (like the 90th percentile), the overall distribution, and so on.

Comment: @SalMangiafico With sample sizes 31 and 26 respectively, wouldn't it be challenging to compare the 90th percentiles?

Comment: @dipetkov , you have a point.  But it's no different that estimating the median with a sample with an even number of observations:  the quantile has to be interpolated either way.

Answer (score 1):

If one population has a non-normal distribution, you should try using a nonparametric test such as the [Wilcoxon rank-sum test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) to test whether distributions differ. Nonparametric tests do not make assumptions about normality.

Comment: +1, since this is a viable solution. (And someone downvoted without comment). ... However, the Wilcoxon rank sum test is ***not*** under most circumstance a test of the medians.

Comment: @SalMangiafico So should I use this Wilcoxon rank sum test?

Comment: @SalMangiafico thanks for the clarification, I should have specified the location shift assumption. 

Regardless, a Wilcoxon rank sum test should be used here.

Comment: Just to peevish, I also dislike using the phrase "to test whether distributions [ or populations ] differ".  It seems that we use this phrasing a lot when teaching, e.g.   *t*-tests.  But that doesn't really capture what the test is testing for.  For example, `A = (1,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5); B = (2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4)` . Clearly the distributions are different, but a rank-sum test will return a *p*-value of 1.  As will a *t*-test.  But a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test will give a different result.